# Почему может не запрашиваться разрешение на permissions?

Tags: java, android

Я собрал релизную версию попробовал ее поставить на несколько устройств `Meizu MX5`, `Samsung S5` и `OnePlus` так вот на `Meizu MX5` и `Samsung S5` перед установкой приложения открывается форма с запросом о том, что мне нужно подтвердить перечисленные разрешения.

Когда я тот же файл загружаю на `OnePlus` он ничего не спрашивает, сразу устанавливает и все...

От чего это может зависеть?

Comment: от версии андройда.

Comment: под какой версией работают все телефоны на которых тестировали?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид 2 на которых запрашивается работают на 5.1 , тот который не запрашивает на 6.0 ... А как это зависит? Это новая фича 6-ки? Теперь все запрашивается динамически?

Comment: @ZigZag 2 на которых запрашивается работают на 5.1 , тот который не запрашивает на 6.0 ... А как это зависит? Это новая фича 6-ки? Теперь все запрашивается динамически?

Comment: да, запрашивает динамически начиная с 6 версии. Если поставить `compileSdkVersion 22`, То на 23 будет так же само, как и на предыдущих

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если телефон запущен под Android 6.0 (API level 23) или выше, **И** приложение имеет targetSdkVersion 23  или выше, то приложение запрашивает разрешения динамически.

Если телефон запущен под Android 5.1 (API level 22) или ниже, **ИЛИ** приложение имеет targetSdkVersion 22  или ниже, то приложение запрашивает разрешения во время инсталляции.

Comment: Я знаком с этим. Мое приложение работает с камерой и я делаю такой динамический запрос на камеру. Но это единственное разрешение которое приложение запрашивает динамически... Все остальные разрешения (READ_PHONE_STATE WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE GET_ACCOUNTS`) не реализованы динамически, но приложение все разно работает...

Comment: какой targetSdkVersion приложения?

Comment: Вроде разобрался что к чему, только не могу понять один момент, может вы сталкивались с таким... Одно из опасных пермишенов в моем манифесте это `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и для убедительности я пошел в настройки телефона, нашел свое приложение и посмотрел в разрешениях и действительно оно было выключено... Но в процессе работы, приложение отлично все записывает в память устройства... Может это из за того, что память устройства не относится к `EXTERNAL_STORAGE`? Но тогда почему когда я писал код который должен сохранять данные мне нужно было указать этот пермишен... не понятно...

Comment: память устройства не относится к EXTERNAL_STORAGE. К EXTERNAL_STORAGE  относится память, которая может быть в любой момент удалена из телефона, например карты памяти. Этот пермишен вас никто не может "заставить" указать, ведь вы же сам разработчик и сам определяете где должны хранится ваши данные. Хранение данных в EXTERNAL_STORAGE не лучший вариант, т.к. приложение к ним может потерять доступ, но если это позволительно с точки зрения архитектуры, то почему бы и нет..

Answer (score 2):

Динамические разрешения Андроид. Начиная с 6 версии, схема получения разрешений немного изменилась. Статья на Хабре на эту тему - https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/

Comment: Я знаком с этим. Мое приложение работает с камерой и я делаю такой динамический запрос на камеру.  Но это единственное разрешение которое приложение запрашивает динамически... Все остальные разрешения (`READ_PHONE_STATE` `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` GET_ACCOUNTS`) не реализованы динамически, но приложение все разно работает...